# Putting 2 Strings Together to Build URL with ResultSet

Tags: java, string, stringbuilder

I'm trying to build a url from 2 parts of my result set.  The Prop_Value itself is a URL alone, but I need to add a Ven_Item to the end of it.  Here is my code involving the build:

```
String first = (rs1.getString("PROP_VALUE"));   
String second = (rs1.getString("VEN_ITEM"));

String url = (first+second);

URL obj = new URL(url);

HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

int  responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
System.out.println("\nSending 'GET' request to URL : " +url);
System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);


BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
String inputLine;
StringBuffer content = new StringBuffer();
while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
    content.append(inputLine);
    }
    in.close();
    con.disconnect();
```

It will run through, but it is only sending over the PROP_VALUE and not attaching the VEN_ITEM to it, any suggestions?

Comment: What's the value of `second` after you assign it?

Comment: Is there perhaps some unwanted whitespace character?  Did you try using `first.trim()+second.trim()`? Also you can just print both `first` and `second` to console to see what they contain.

Comment: as @Achilles said you could have and space, are you also you that yo have a value in that column? Maybe you need to check for nullity there

Comment: Are you sure that `obj` is producing a valid URL query string? An example might be helpful.

Comment: I just tried printing to see the values and PROP_VALUE prints, but the VEN_ITEM(second) doesn't.  I added the trim and it doesn't print either, it just prints a blank line.

Comment: It was an issue with my SQL and the value it was passing, thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think something wrong with your first and second variable values. Please check. Bcoz, below code is running fine.

```
    String first = ("https://stackoverflow.com/questions");
    String second = ("/48545905/putting-2-strings-together-to-build-url-with-resultset");

    String url = (first+second);

    URL obj = null;
    try {
        obj = new URL(url);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    HttpsURLConnection con = null;
    try {
        con = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    int  responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
    System.out.println("\nSending 'GET' request to URL : " +url);
    System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);


    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    StringBuffer content = new StringBuffer();
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        content.append(inputLine);
    }
    System.out.println(content);
    in.close();
    con.disconnect();
```

Got the Below console output:

> Sending 'GET' request to URL :
>   [Putting 2 Strings Together to Build URL with ResultSet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48545905/putting-2-strings-together-to-build-url-with-resultset)
>   Response Code : 200